# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, wordpress, parse-error, php-parse-error

I am trying to use following codes to have an email share button in a WordPress website. But adding this codes in single.php shows "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in .......... in line 72". 
Please help me someone to fix this issue.

```
<?php echo "<a href="mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&body=<?php the_title('','',true); ?>%20%20%3A%20%20<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20<?php the_permalink(); ?>%20%29" title="Email to a friend/colleague" target="_blank">Share via Email</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: please re-write this script its very bad!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code that could easily be solved by using a decent IDE.

Comment: Well both of your comments are really unhelpful, he obviously can't rewrite the script otherwise he wouldn't be asking for help, and if he is using something like Sublime Text 2 or similar then he wouldn't have access to debugging options (by default). If you're going to comment, make sure it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes or change the inner double-quotes to single quotes

**[edit]**

Something like this:

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20'. bloginfo('name') .'&body='.the_title('','',true).'%20%20%3A%20%20'. get_the_excerpt() .'%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20'. the_permalink() .'%20%29" title="Email to a friend/colleague" target="_blank">Share via Email</a>'; 
?>
```

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge in PHP so unable to edit. Could you please help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is another problem arisen. Output of the codes is "TestThis is the Title of the Posthttp://localhost/wordpress/?p=1Share via Email" where I think it should be "Share via Email".  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Finally a great guy, from another forum, found the issue. Here is the correct codes              <a href="mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20<?php echo rawurlencode(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>&body=<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_title()); ?>%20%20%3A%20%20<?php echo rawurlencode(get_the_excerpt()); ?>%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20<?php echo rawurlencode(get_permalink()); ?>%20%29" title="Email to a friend/colleague" target="_blank">Share via Email</a>

Answer (score 2):

Escape your quotes:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&body=<?php the_title('','',true); ?>%20%20%3A%20%20<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20<?php the_permalink(); ?>%20%29\" title=\"Email to a friend/colleague\" target="_blank\">Share via Email</a>"; ?>
```

**Tip:** Use a good text editor that supports syntax highlighting. That'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: Or use single quote symbols `'...'`.

Comment: @Eugene: except that the link contains 12 single quotes inside it.

Comment: Hi Amal, Thank you. The codes didn't fix the issue. @Eugene tried but didn't work. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @AmalMurali, right. Forgot to scroll further and check. No single quotation marks this time)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php echo "<a href='mailto:type%20email%20address%20here?subject=I%20wanted%20to%20share%20this%20post%20with%20you%20from%20<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&body=<?php the_title('','',true); ?>%20%20%3A%20%20<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20<?php the_permalink(); ?>%20%29' title='Email to a friend/colleague' target='_blank'>Share via Email</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Bindiya, thank you. Parse error problem fixed but new problem arise with the codes.

Comment: what is it user29378?

Comment: output of the codes "&body=%20%20%3A%20%20%20%20%2D%20%20%28%20%20%29' title='Email to a friend/colleague' target='_blank'>Share via Email"

Comment: for that you can directly write code .not necessary to add '%20'.

Comment: Didn't work Bindiya :(